# Providing user defined column names in AWS glue

Tags: parquet, aws-glue

I have a lot of parquet files. I need to read them through Amazon Glue and then provide column names to the table that is being read.

The problem is parquet already have column names which is being read by the crawler and show it in the table. Is it possible to provide my column names to these parquet files in glue

Answer (score 2):

To replace the detected column names with names of your own, you could either:

- Use one of the following [build in transformations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/built-in-transforms.html) on DynamicFrame

  - ApplyMapping - Applies a declarative mapping to this DynamicFrame and returns a new DynamicFrame with those mappings applied. (source column, source type, target column, target type)
  - RenameField - Renames a field in this DynamicFrame and returns a new DynamicFrame with the field renamed. (oldName -> newName)

See the [Scala](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-etl-scala-apis-glue-dynamicframe.html) or [Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html) ETL programming guides for more detail.

Or try updating the data catalog field names manually if you don't need to continuously re-crawl the data (or if you do, it is possible to prevent a glue crawler from updating existing data catalog tables via the [crawler configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-configuration.html)).

Alternatively, if your requirements are more discrete, the `map` transform is available to convert each DynamicRecord in the DynamicFrame to a new DynamicRecord of your choosing.